# How to install Flutter in Windows 10?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I am **installing flutter** in my windows 10 but when I check that is everything alright through **flutter doctor** command in cmd then there is some error shown in following picture.

Error image

[image]

Comment: did you install git?

Comment: Bro, you don't have internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see at the bottom right corner, you don't have an internet connection and thus, it can't reach `github.com`, which it seemingly needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download a fresh install of flutter sdk and follow the necessary steps from here.. https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows
2. Be sure to register the path in the environmental variables
3. Be sure to install git
4. Be sure you are connected to the internet along the process

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Download the Flutter SDK. We’ll have to download the Flutter SDK file in order to work with flutter. We can easily download it from the official website of Flutter.[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqj1d.png)

**Step 2:** Set Environment variable path. After downloading Flutter SDK, extract the file and copy the path of the bin folder.
[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IAKP.png)

Press WIN + R and paste the following: rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNyJF.png)

Now click on new and paste the path that was copied earlier and save.
[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEyPe.png)

Now We have to set up the Visual Studio Code for the Flutter. We have to install two extensions in order to use flutter. The very first extension is Flutter and 2nd is Dart. Note that Dart is the programming language that is used in flutter for the application development for both and android and iOS.

**Step 3:** Installing Flutter in Visual Studio Code
[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4g93.png)

**Step 4:** Now install Dart in Visual Studio Code
[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLd1q.png)

**Step 5:** Now we have successfully added Flutter and Dart to the Visual studio code, now let’s check if flutter is installed or not. For this we will open a new terminal in Visual Studio Code and type the following “flutter –version”, if everything is fine then it will normally show the version of the installed flutter.
[click for preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfrxw.png)